# calculate an approximate value of integral

Tags: numerical-methods

Calculate an approximate value of integral : $$\int_1^{3.4}\frac {2}{\sqrt{x}+x}$$

Take 8-subintervals $n=8$ by using trapezoidal rule

How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$h=\frac{b-a}{n}$

$h=\frac{3.4-1}{8}=0.3$

then the table of discrete points of the function :

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+x}$

then using the trapezoidal rule

$It=h/2[(y0+yn)+2\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} yi]$

Comment: you are welcome